# SharePoint 2010 to 2013 Migration limitations?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, migration, limitations

Are there any limitations for content database size for migrating from SharePoint 2010 to 2013. Any best practices for migrating a content db of 600 GB?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. You can migrate such DB.
2. Before moving, check can some data be discarded, (ie. Do you need to move all versions?) SP2010 and SP2013 have different versioning model (see Shredded Storage)
3. Do inventory of custom solutions if any - check do you have access to source code.
4. Build test sp2013 farm.
5. Do a test migration, check sites do they work in compatibility mode.
6. If they work ok in compatibility run upgrade site by site and test - for that you might need to upgrade custom solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one site collections in that content database then i would split the database and make the small size.

- If more than one site collections you have in it,

  - Create a new content database and move the couple of site collection in it.
  - i would bring down the size of content database 150gb per db.

But if you have only one site collection and that is 600GB then

- Clean up the site collection (clear the recyclbin, delete the unwanted documents, delete unused sites, strict the version, remove unused templates, webpart or solutions etc)
- Now create the inventory list i.e. what is your configuration, custom solution, webpart, custom templates etc
- It is highly recommend perform a test migration before actual migration.
- Build new farm, create web application, deploy customization, configure service app etc.
- Now perform the backup and restore of content database into SharePoint 2013 farm
- Mount it to SharePoint 2013.
- Test, test and test (functionality, post migration issue etc).
- Once satisfied then perform actual migration.

[Checklist for database-attach upgrade (SharePoint 2013)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607663.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)